# How correctly use libvlc (C++) to get frames from h264 videostream?

Tags: c++, h.264, libvlc

I am interested in getting working a solution where i am using libvlc library to get video frames from h264 stream. I have set callback to `libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks` and received following info from my callback function (`format_callback`) parameters: chroma: "J420", width: 1088 , height: 1922

When i call in main

```
Player p;
p.play("rtsp://path/to/camera?videocodec=h264");
```

it print outs following errors

```
chroma "J420" width: 1088 , height: 1922
[00007fddfc001268] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
[00007fddfc001268] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
[00007fddfc001268] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR
[h264 @ 0x7fde1c06cea0] error while decoding MB 24 111, bytestream -15
[swscaler @ 0x7fddfc002ca0] bad dst image pointers
[swscaler @ 0x7fddfc002ca0] bad dst image pointers
```

My guess is that there is problem with buffers and their sizes. Where, which type and how big buffers to use to get video frame by frame? Later I plan to forward the frame data to QImage. Below is the Player.h file:

```
const int ResoHeight = 1922;
const int ResoWidth = 1088;
const int BytesPerPixel = 3; // not sure about this

struct ImageData
{
  QVector<unsigned char> raw;
  QVector<unsigned char> picture;

  ImageData()
  {
    raw.resize(BytesPerPixel * ResoHeight * ResoWidth);
    picture.resize(BytesPerPixel * ResoHeight * ResoWidth);
  }
};

class Player : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Player(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  ~Player();

  void play(const std::string& path);

signals:
  void newImage(const QImage& image);

private:
  libvlc_instance_t* vlcInstance;
  libvlc_media_player_t* player;
  libvlc_media_t* media;
  ImageData buffer;
};
```

Player.cpp is following:

```
namespace {
void* lock_frame(void *opaque, void **planes)
{
  ImageData* buf = (ImageData*)(opaque);
  *planes = buf->raw.data();
  return buf->picture.data();
}

void unlock_frame(void *opaque, void *picture, void *const *planes)
{
  // will be logic to announce new image
}

unsigned format_callback(void** opaque, char* chroma, unsigned *width, unsigned *height, unsigned *pitches, unsigned *lines)
{
  qDebug() << "chroma:" << QString(chroma) << "width:" << *width << ", height:" << *height;

  *pitches= (*width) * BytesPerPixel;
  *lines= *height;

  return 1;
}

} // namespace

Player::Player(QObject* parent)
  : QObject(parent)
  , vlcInstance(libvlc_new(0, nullptr))
  , player(libvlc_media_player_new(vlcInstance))
  , media(nullptr)
{
}

Player::~Player()
{
  libvlc_media_player_stop(player);
  libvlc_media_player_release(player);
  libvlc_release(vlcInstance);
}

void Player::play(const std::string& path)
{
  media = libvlc_media_new_location(vlcInstance, path.c_str());
  libvlc_media_player_set_media(player, media);
  libvlc_media_release(media);

  libvlc_video_set_callbacks(player, lock_frame, unlock_frame, nullptr, &buffer);
  libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(player, format_callback, nullptr);

  libvlc_media_player_play(player);
}
```

Comment: 'buffer' is not initialized. you should init it in the format_callback function.

Comment: 'buffer' is type of ImageData and it is initiliazed in its constructor. Of course it would be correct to initialize it in `format_callback` function, but it shouldn't be the cause of the problem. Tried it by moving the buffer resize methods to `format_callback`. Same errors.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize that. J420 chroma is a planar YUV format https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV/ . Which means you have to provide 3 image pointers in lock_frame. If you just want an RGB(RV24) image see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/40365353/1632887

Comment: That was it, thank you. I finally used RV32 format. If you move your comment as an answer then i can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J420 chroma is a [planar YUV](http://wiki.videolan.org/YUV) format. Which means you have to provide 3 dimensional `pitches` and `lines` in `format_callback` and 3 different `planes` pointers (for each plane) in `lock_frame` function. If you just want an RGB(RV24) image, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40365353/1632887).